# Displaying alternate keys in SQL Server management studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

In the case where you have a Identity field as a primary key in your table, but also have an "alternate (primary) key" defined on multiple other fields in the table, is there a way (perhaps via a 3rd party plug-in) that one can have the alternate key fields be displayed in the schema diagram as other tools can do?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of - the identification of such other unique keys can be done either by inspecting the unique constraints/indexes on the table or perhaps with extended properties either on the table or the columns involved.  But I'm not aware of anything which will show that information in SSMS.